# IP Config.. When I go to run it, it pops up for a less than a second and disappears. Windows 8 (Asus i7 notebook)

Tags: windows-8, ipconfig

EVery time I try to run ipconfig it shows up for less than a second and disappears before I can use it or do anything. I have a Window 8 notebook computer, 64bit.

Answer (score 4):

You have to start command line by running 'cmd' and then type 'ipconfig'.

Answer (score 1):

Console programs should be run from a console.